# Getting all the ID's from a specific column automatically (i.e. not having to select a row) in a JTable

Tags: java, database, jtable

I would like,as the title suggests, to be able to get all the values in an ID column from a JTable without the user actually selecting a row (and thus ID).Lets say there are two results in the JTable, that means there are two items in the ID column. Is there a way that I extract these values automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much depends on your goal, but you can

- Traverse the [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html), invoking `getColumnClass()` for each column; use `getValueAt()` to examine the value for a particular row.

  ```
  DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
  …
  for (int col = 0; col < model.getColumnCount(); col++) {
      Class type = model.getColumnClass(col);
  }
  ```
- Use the methods of [`DatabaseMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) & [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) to get the details of a relation's attributes, *before* inserting the data into the `TableModel`.